# not able to find tfjs-node bindings

Tags: python, node.js, tensorflow, tfjs-node, tensorflow.js

I am trying tfjs-node in my machine for one of my projects and i keep getting the below issue.

```
Error: The Node.js native addon module (tfjs_binding.node) can not be found at path: /Users/pavanmantha/Pavans/ML-Practice/nodejs+tfjs/nodejs_tfjs/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node/lib/napi-v6/tfjs_binding.node.
```

My environment is as below:
OS: MAC OSX Catalina 10.15.6
Node: 14.5.0
Python: 3.8.3

Please suggest me some way, as i tried reinstalling all dependencies and changed my node versions. nothing helped.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the Issue. by following the below process.

```
xcode-select --install
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
```

Then i reinstalled the xcode tools by removing and reinstalling them

```
sudo rm -r -f /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
xcode-select --install
```

once the xcode tools got installed i ran the command as below.

```
npm rebuild @tensorflow/tfjs-node --build-from-source
```

All working fine. Thanks @tornikeo for your path way i followed it to resolve

Answer (score 0):

From this [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/2046)
Try running this command

```
npm rebuild @tensorflow/tfjs-node --build-from-source
```

Does this solve your problem?